# how to get filter data between two dates in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am working on Django project How to get filter data between two dates I mean (from-date and to-date) **mfdate** is a foreign key and coming from another model. how can I do this can anyone help me to solve this problem I have tried multiple time but it is not working

here is my Code

**models.py**

```
 class ManufacturingYM(models.Model):
     ManufacturingYMID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     ManufacturingDate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, blank= True,null=True)

     def __str__(self):
         return str(self.ManufacturingDate)

  class Car(models.Model):
      CarID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      CarName = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Car Name")
      mfdate = models.ForeignKey(ManufacturingYM, blank= True,null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name="Manufacturing Date")

      def __str__(self):
          return self.CarName
```

**views.py**

```
   def searchdd(request):

      carForm = Car.objects.all()
      fromdate = str(request.POST.get('from_date'))
      todate = str(request.POST.get('to_date')) 

      if fromdate:    
          carForm= Car.objects.filter(mfdate=fromdate)    
      if todate:
          carForm= Car.objects.filter(mfdate=todate)

      context = {'carForm':carForm} 
      return render(request, 'app/searchdd.html', context)
```

**home.html**

```
     <form method="post" id="indexForm" action="/searchdd" data-cars-url="{% url 'ajax_load_cars' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="" class="white">From Year</label>
        <select name="from_date" id="fromdate" class="dp-list">
          <option disabled selected="true" value="">--select Year--</option>
          {% for mfd in manfd %}
          <option value="{{car.CarID}}">{{mfd.ManufacturingDate|date:'Y'}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="" class="white">To Year</label>
        <select name="to_date" id="todate" class="dp-list">
          <option disabled selected="true" value="">--select Year--</option>
          {% for mfd in manfd %}
          <option value="{{car.CarID}}">{{mfd.ManufacturingDate|date:'Y'}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `from_date` and `get_date` have as format `YYY-MM-DD`, then you can filter with:

```
def searchdd(request):
      carForm = Car.objects.all()
      fromdate = request.POST.get('from_date')
      todate = request.POST.get('to_date')

      if fromdate:    
          carForm = carForm.filter(mfdate__ManufacturingDate__gte=fromdate)
      if todate:
          carForm = carForm.filter(mfdate__ManufacturingDate__lte=todate)

      context = {'carForm':carForm} 
      return render(request, 'app/searchdd.html', context)
```

If the request does not contain a `from_date` or `to_date`, then that filter is omitted. If both are thus omitted, all `Car`s will be returned. If `to_date` is `2021-1-1`, then you will retrieve all `Car`s that have been manufactued before or on January 1<sup>st</sup>, 2021.

As for the form, you should format the items correctly, so:

```
<select name="from_date" id="fromdate" class="dp-list">
    <option disabled selected="true" value="">--select Year--</option>
        {% for mfd in manfd %}
            <option value="{{ mfd.ManufacturingDate.year }}-1-1">{{mfd.ManufacturingDate|date:'Y'}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
</select>
```

the same for the `to_date`, but then it is `{{ mfd.ManufacturingDate.year }}-12-31`.

Comment: ['“None” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.']

I have done like you did but after this error is coming

Comment: @daniyalakhtarakhtar: you should remove the `str(...)`s from the `request.POST.get('from_date')` line (same with the `to_date`). It makes no sense to call `str(..)` since the item is either a string, or does not exists.

Comment: but all cars are coming still filter is not working

Comment: @daniyalakhtarakhtar: well if it is `None` it means you did not submit a POST request where `from_date` and `to_date` are in the request. Perhaps you have send these with another name, or you made a GET request.

Comment: @daniyalakhtarakhtar: your `<option value="{{ car.carId }}">` by the way so it will *not* make a request with an `YYYY-MM-DD`, but simply with a single integer.

Comment: @daniyalakhtarakhtar: also note that searches typically are done with a GET request, since one *retrieves* data. POST requests are normally done to create, update, or remove entities.

Comment: yes I have fixed that but still not working

Comment: @daniyalakhtarakhtar: exactly what request do you see on the terminal? Are you sure the given view is triggered?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237764/discussion-between-daniyalakhtar-akhtar-and-willem-van-onsem).